# Prepare multiple statments before executing them in a transaction?

Tags: php, pdo

Is it ok to prepare multiple statments before executing them?

```
$db = PDO('..connection info...');
$cats_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM cats');
$dogs_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM dogs');

$cats_stmt->execute();
$cats = $cats_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);//list of cats

$dogs_stmt->execute();
$dogs = $dogs_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);//list of dogs
```

This would come in handy for loops where 2 statements with different variables need to be executed after each other.
like this:

```
$stmt_addcat = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO cats (name,age) VALUES(?,?)');
$stmt_adddog = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO dogs (name,age) VALUES(?,?)');

foreach($cat_n_dog as $bunch){
  $db->beginTransaction();
  $dog_name = $bunch['dog']['name'];
  $dog_age  = $bunch['dog']['age'];
  $stmt_adddog->bindParam(1,$dog_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt_adddog->bindParam(2,$dog_age,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $result = $stmt_adddog->execute();
  if($result===false){
    $db->rollBack();
    continue;
  }
  $cat_name = $bunch['cat']['name'];
  $cat_age  = $bunch['cat']['age'];
  $stmt_addcat->bindParam(1,$cat_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt_addcat->bindParam(2,$cat_age,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $result = $stmt_addcat->execute();
  if($result===false){
    $db->rollBack();
    continue;
  }
  $db->commit();
}
```

I am asking because I had situations where PDO would act buggy and throw errors on the sqlite driver, so I'm wondering if the above example is even supposed to work.

p.s. examples are made-up on the spot.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use PDO the way you describe. The only problem is that you use `beginTransaction()` in your `foreach` statement, which defeats the purpose of transactions but I don't know whether that's a mistake you made during typing of this example or if it's something you actually use.

Comment: post errors thrown by pdo sqlite driver

Comment: @Eugene Manuilov I can't manage to replicate the errors right now, I fear it was some-kind of bug, it's not important anyway, I just wanted to know if it's normal to prepare statements and later execute them in a transaction within a loop.

Comment: @Michael J.V. I haven't done the transcation thing, but I didn't know that it defeated the purpose, whats wrong with it? should I start the transaction before the foreach? and if I do, then should the loop break instead of continuing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll post as answer since comments don't allow enough space.

Yes, you can prepare several prepared statements and then execute them in a loop, there's nothing wrong with that.

The transaction part is wrong. If you want to execute all or no queries, you need to start your transaction outside of the loop (same with commit).
That's where PHP's `try/catch` comes in handy.

```
$db = PDO('..connection info...');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // Set error mode to exceptions

try
{
    $stmt_addcat = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO cats (name,age) VALUES(?,?)');
    $stmt_adddog = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO dogs (name,age) VALUES(?,?)');

    $db->beginTransaction();

    foreach($cat_n_dog as $bunch) { } // Do your foreach binding and executing here 

    $db->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $db->rollBack();

    echo "Error occurred. Error message: ". $e->getMessage() .". File: ". $e->getFile() .". Line: ". $e->getLine();
}
```

Comment: I thought that each transaction "groups" the queries, so by inserting each cat n dog pair in a transaction within the loop would allow the loop to continue or fail on one query pair. p.s. does your foreach include rollBack's?

Comment: You'd be executing 1 cat query and 1 dog query the way you constructed your transaction. Point of transactions is all or none, why would you group them 2 by 2? I forgot rollback in my example, I edited it so it should be clearer.

Answer (score -1):

just wanted to comment here that when I placed the code provided by **Michael J.V.** into my project I had a smile on my face that I could not remove.

This code with PDO is so beautiful.  I just prepared and executed over 500 queries with rollback... **HOW ELEGANT**!

For a bit more explanation inside the foreach loop... your code should look simmilar to

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array('name', 'age'));
```

Comment: Actually you prepare it outside the foreach loop, and only once for every type of query, the loop only needs to contain the `$stmt->execute(...)` calls. Hope this makes your smile even bigger :)