# Delete function not working within a transaction pdo php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having similar problems as this colleague: [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790402/pdo-refuses-to-delete-a-row-of-data-in-specific-table)

I am surprised that a Delete function within a transaction with pdo does not behave properly. If I use the delete function alone in a pdo it works perfectly but when I combine the delete function with an update function in a transaction it stops working (only first query works). I have tried all the answer and tips from the old thread but nothing seems to work. Can someone help me here?

The code that I am working with:

```
function denyactionevent(){


        try {
            $$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, true);
            $$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

             $this->conn->beginTransaction();

        // product update query
        $query = "UPDATE 
                    " . $this->table_name . " 
                SET 
                    accepted = :accepted 

                WHERE
                    id = :id";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // bind variable values
        $stmt->bindParam(':accepted', $this->accepted);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        $query2 = "DELETE  
                   FROM event_case 
                   WHERE reference = :id
                ";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query2);

        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);


    // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();   


    $this->conn->commit();
    return true;



} catch (Exception $e) {
  $stmt->rollBack();
  return false;
}
    }
```

Comment: it could depend on how you're calling that `denyactionevent()` function (which is unknown) and if variable scope is an issue.

Comment: It does not seem the case because the first query in that transaction seems to be working properly.

Comment: `$$this->setAttribute` - isn't that one $ too many?

Comment: @VolkerK would error reporting have caught that?

Comment: You might want to check the results of your calls to `$stmt->execute();`. Are they successful or do they return FALSE? If they do return false, what is the error causing it?

Comment: no response. Ok, well if that double `$$` is the issue, check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The double $$ is not the problem even deleting them the Problem persists.

Comment: "would error reporting have caught that?" - it should have caused a fatal error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class ... could not be converted to ..." @Fred

Comment: This link might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598215/prepare-multiple-statments-before-executing-them-in-a-transaction